# Elasticsearch CommonTerms Name property explanation

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm new to Elasticsearch but used Lucene.net before. Could someone please explain what the name parameter is for? Because i can't find an explanation on the web (neither on their official docs page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/common-terms-usage.html).

I meant this field: `.Name("named_query")`

```
q
.CommonTerms(c => c
    .Field(p => p.Description)
    .Analyzer("standard")
    .Boost(1.1)
    .CutoffFrequency(0.001)
    .DisableCoord()
    .HighFrequencyOperator(Operator.And)
    .LowFrequencyOperator(Operator.Or)
    .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
    .Name("named_query")
    .Query("nelly the elephant not as a")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Name()` maps to `_name` within the JSON query DSL. [Named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html), as they are known, can be used to understand which queries in a `bool` query a given hit has matched on.

Comment: Now at least i know that it's something that i currently don't need. Looks like it's not required. I tried to run my search query without it and everything worked just fine without it. Is this only for boolean queries? Could you provide an code example where this would be useful? If it's not too much work else i'm satisfied with your answer as well. Thanks! :)

Comment: There's an example request in the linked article :) The only time it's useful is when you have a `bool` query and wish to know which queries within a `bool` query a given hit matched on. Other than this, you don't need it